# How can I plot variables in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, pointers, plot

So, I'm trying to make a plot in the following format:

```
print(levelplot(Z ~ X*Y, data=data))
```

X and Y are column names in the dataframe. If I have a list of the column names, how can I go through them and plot every column against every other column?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a vector of colnames, say `cols`, you can loop over all the combinations of those column names, each time creating the plot, like this:

```
plots = lapply(combn(cols,2,simplify = F), function(v) {
  levelplot(as.formula(paste0("Z~",v[1],"*",v[2])), data=d)
})
```

Now, `plots` is a list of `levelplot()` objects, which you can then plot, for example, like this:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]])
```